# Flexibly unpack returned tuple in python

Tags: python, function, return, tuples

In Python, I can return multiple values from a function like this:

```py
def myfunc():
    return 1, 2, 3
```

When I call this function, I need to unpack the values like this:

```py
a, b, c = myfunc()
# a = 1, b = 2, c = 3
```

If I try this, I'll get the whole tuple:

```py
a = myfunc()
# a = (1, 2, 3)
```

Is there anyway I can make the code above make `a = 1` without changing the way the function is called? I realize I can do something like `a, _, _ = myfunc()`, but I don't want to change the way the function is called. **I can only change the function definition.**

In other words I want something like this:

```py
a, b, c = myfunc()
# a = 1, b = 2, c = 3

a, b = myfunc()
# a = 1, b = 2

a = myfunc()
# a = 1
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the star notation:

```
a, *_ = myfunc()
```

This assigns 1 to `a` and the rest of the tuple to the
"anonymous" variable `_`.

Answer (score 0):

It has already been mentioned by @DYZ above, you can retrieve the specified number of tuples from your function like this:

```
def myfunc():
    return 1,2,3

a,b,c = myfunc()
print (a,b,c)

a,b,*_ = myfunc()
print (a,b)

a,*_  = myfunc()
print(a)
```

Note that we must carefully specify the 'discard' or *ignore* or 'anonymous variable' once, if needed.

[image: Output inside Pydev]